# Obtain the HDF5 file format version of a file

Tags: hdf5, hdf

Given a certain HDF5 file ([HDF5 format](https://www.hdfgroup.org/)), how can I know the version of the file format that has been used for its creation?

Context. It is said in the [documentation](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/faq/bkfwd-compat.html) that when you create/write a file the library the following applies for backward compatibility:

> An HDF5 Library of any given release is designed to read all existing
>   HDF5 files from that or any prior release. Although major versions
>   sometimes contain features that require additions and/or changes to
>   the HDF5 file format, the library will by default write out files that
>   conform to a maximum compatibility principle. That is, **files are
>   written with the earliest version of the file format that describes
>   the information**, rather than always using the latest version possible.
>   This provides the best forward compatibility by allowing the maximum
>   number of older versions of the library to read new files.

I have tried tools like h5stat but it does not output the info that I want.

Thank you.

Comment: you mean the hdf5 library version? i think all the programs use the same xc library anyway

Comment: @kakk11 I mean, if a hdf5 file is created using the hdf5 library version 1.10.x I will be able to open it with a program that has the library version 1.8.x if the file doesn't have any features of the version 1.10.x. However, without trying to open it with my program, can I know in advance the minimum library version that it is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer in the last question https://ftp.hdfgroup.org/hdf5-quest.html#h5dumpvers

Q: Can you add an option to h5dump or h5ls to print the version of a file ?

A: No, we do not plan on adding this option. Users should use attributes to specify the version of a file. There are many reasons why we shouldn't add this. For example, different objects in the file could be created or modified by different versions of the library.

Comment: Thanks. However, I'm not sure if they are speaking about a custom parameter that the user can use to specify the version of a file, or about the version of the HDF5 library.

Comment: Well the last sentence is clear about the possibility of different library versions used to write the same file, so I understand it is users duty to write down what library version is compatible with the file. That said, I do not agree with HDF5 groups opinion and I believe the feature of compatibility check of library versions, could be beneficial for the user and would not be that hard to implement.